# ReactJS - How to toggle button that got clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in React, I don't know what keyword to find my solution. I have many `<button>` and just want to toggle the button that got clicked. How to achieve that?

Here's what i've been trying...

```
export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState(false);
  const btnText = text ? 'Foo' : 'Bar';
  const handleClick = () => setText((prevState) => !prevState);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>{btnText}</button>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>{btnText}</button>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>{btnText}</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add unique id on each buttons, and you can change your code like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const listOfButtons = [0, 1, 2];
  const [btnClicked, setBtnClicked] = useState([]);
  const handleClick = (id) => setBtnClicked({...btnClicked, [id]: !btnClicked[id]});

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {listOfButtons.map(id => (
        <button type="button" onClick={() => handleClick(id)}>{`${btnClicked[id] ? 'clicked' : 'not clicked'}`}</button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a function without the parens, you're just passing the definition. In your onClick, invoke your function like this:

```
onClick={()=>handleClick()}
```

if you were to invoke the handleClick function w/o it being inside an arrow function, then you would get an infinite loop.

```
onClick={handleClick()}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function App() {
  //each button needs its own state
  const [text, setText] = React.useState({
    button234423: false,
    button456645: false,
    button398375: false
  });

  //target button in state by element id
  const handleClick = e => {
    const id = e.target.id;
    setText(text => ({ ...text, [id]: !text[id] }));
  };

  //map state to return button element with key as id and value as conditional
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {Object.entries(text).map(([key, value]) => {
        return (
          <button type="button" key={key} id={key} onClick={handleClick}>
            {value ? "Foo" : "Bar"}
          </button>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently `state` shared to all the button. Keep it as a separate component

```
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button />
      <Button />
      <Button />
    </div>
  );
}


export const Button = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState(false);
  const btnText = text ? 'Foo' : 'Bar';
  const handleClick = () => setText((prevState) => !prevState);

  return <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>{btnText}</button>
}

export default App;
```